# Addressing two unrelated arrays with [base+index*scale] without UB

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to figure out how to get GCC or Clang to use `[base+index*scale]` addressing to index two unrelated arrays, like this, to save an `add` instruction:

```
;; rdi is srcArr, rsi is srcArr - dstArr, rax is len of arrays
Loop:
  mov     ecx, dword ptr [rdi + 4*rsi]
  mov     dword ptr [rdi], ecx
  add     rdi, 4
  cmp     rdi, rax
  jb      .Loop
```

The C++ code below achieves this, but because `dst` and `src` are unrelated, subtracting them is UB, even though the difference is never dereferenced. (I think this will nonetheless work on all x86/64 hardware though.)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

void offset(float* __restrict__ dst, const float* __restrict__ src, size_t n) {
    const float *enddst = dst + n;
    const std::ptrdiff_t offset = src - dst;
    while (dst < enddst) {
        std::memcpy(dst, /* src */ dst + offset, sizeof(float));
        dst++;
    }
}
```

(Ignore the silly loop body, it's just for illustration as something using the addresses.)

Is there a way to do this without UB?

[godbolt with non-UB and UB version](https://godbolt.org/z/lhK80Q)

Comment: Why do you want to use `std::memcpy(dst, dst+offset...)` when you can use `std::memcpy(dst, src...)`?

Comment: @RSahu it saves an `add` instruction. Editing question to add that now.

Comment: You can probably safely do `const uintptr_t offset = reinterpret_cast <uintptr_t> (src) - reinterpret_cast <uintptr_t> (dst);`.

Comment: I think this is going to depend a lot on what the loop body actually is.  Even if we find a  change that produces the code you want in this toy example, it's not particularly likely that it will also work in your real code.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be `*dst = dst[offset] * 2.0;` to avoid the memcpy distraction.  As Paul says, `uintptr_t` is a good way to go if you want to take advantage of the flat memory model to do stuff like this.  But unfortunately GCC and clang think they know what they're doing and will optimize it however they want.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82369 is a more hacky example where one pointer advances twice as fast as the other (2 loads feeding a `packuswb`), doing all the pointer math with `uintptr_t`.  GCC just does 2 pointer increments. :/

Comment: As long as `src` and `dst` are aligned in memory I don't see a problem, but that's a bold assumption. In any case, by definition doing `dst + (any out of bound index)` is UB, so I'm not sure what you're trying to run from here since you will be doing that no matter what.

Comment: @PaulSanders @PeterCordes `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`? It's not known if `src` has a higher or lower addr than `dst`. I suppose `uintptr_t` would wrap and still work, but want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something subtle.

Comment: I used `uintptr_t` because unsigned wraparound is well-defined in C and C++, and it's possible for subtracting addresses of 2 different objects to overflow `intptr_t` (signed overflow UB).  e.g. on an x86-64 Linux kernel, a 32-bit process has the whole 4GiB of virtual address space to itself.  (GCC defines the max size of one object as 2GiB so `ptrdiff_t` is safe from overflow when subtracting `char*` pointers within one array,  But different objects don't benefit from that guarantee.)  And yes, everything does work out with unsigned wrapping if necessary.